# How can i turn "azimuth" to a variable?

Tags: android

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
            float azimuth = event.values[0];
            textViewX.setText("Sensor Irány :" + azimuth);
```

How can i turn "azimuth" to a variable? I cant make my FileWriter code to write this data to a file. It cant resolve azimuth as avariable.

```
fw = new FileWriter(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/DataLog.csv",
                    true);
BufferedWriter br = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            br.append(azimuth);
        br.append("\r\n");
        br.close();
        fw.close();
```

If i write azimuth to this code for the FileWriter to write it to a file, i got this error: "azimuth cannot be resolved to a variable"

Comment: dont understand your question...

Comment: Can you include the actual error you're getting?

Comment: I think your problem is the scope of the variable.

Comment: Is that second code block also inside onSensorChanged(), or somewhere else? If it's in another function, are you passing azimuth to it? Keyser might be right about scope.

Comment: It is under the onLocationChanged, for the gps data. I have to put the onSensorChanged under the onLocationChanged or what means that scope of a variable?

Comment: I'd recommend you get some programming experience doing some tutorials (maybe just in Java without complicating things with Android concepts) so that you can get the hang of basic programming concepts before you try and tackle a more complicated project.

Comment: Also, could you please update your question with that information? (I.e., that the second code block is in a different function.) It's information that's critical to understanding the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that your azimuth variable is out of scope from where you're trying to use it. It's defined inside onSensorChanged(), whereas you're trying to access it from onLocationChanged(). A variable is only accessible within the code block (lines of code surrounded by curly braces) where it's defined, after it is defined. So you can't access a variable defined in one function from inside the body of a different function.

In order to use the value of azimuth in onLocationChanged(), you need to redefine it there, or (in onSensorChanged()) assign its value to a global variable that onLocationChanged() will then be able to access.

Take a look at the [wiki on scope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28computer_science%29) for more information on what scope is.